# Cannot view LaTeX on the Comments section and the Title in the stack exchange app

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, comments

Sorry, I don't know if this question should be asked here (feel free to remove if this doesn't), since this is only regarding the stack exchange app, my main concern is that I cannot view LaTeX on the comments section and the title, I don't know if this is a problem with the android version I have, or compatibility with my phone (which probably isn't) or a bug in the App. Is there anyone else who is facing the same issue? This happens with other communities too.

Android version: 4.2.2 (Jellybean)

App version: 1.0.75 (latest available version for my phone)

[image: here's a picture for reference]

You can see that the LaTeX doesn't seem to be parsed in the comments and the title sections, it's taking as plain text.

Comment: Can you post you a pic?

Comment: I occasionally get *[Math processing error]* in bright red colors, but refreshing the page typically fixes that for me (using Android 4.4.2, SE App v1.0.75)

Comment: I can read Math but it is of the form "\$sin (\theta) + \int_{0}^{1}dx$" (I intentionally wrote it this way, because this is what I see), that is, the latex typesetting isn't compiling, or it is treating the whole thing as plain text and not as Latex

Comment: Does tapping the comment not work? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251316/mathjax-disabled-in-comments-on-android

Comment: Oh, great it does work, thanks for that, but MathJax is not rendered in the title of the question though, May be I can live with that

Comment: Further to Chris's comment since that request is marked [meta-tag:status-bydesign], it is unlikely that you'll get MathJax-by-default for comments anywhere in the near future. There's some chance of a more intuitive UI, though, proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256480/easier-mechanism-to-display-mathjax-in-comments). It also looks like [MathJax in the title is also a no-go anytime soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221927/mathjax-borks-in-titles-in-android-app) for technical reasons.